# how can I slice or splice array by value in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm recently learning PHP and making my own project.
I usually array a lot in this app because most of the data I get is from open API.
nevertheless, I faced a problem with dealing array yesterday and can't solve it yet due to my lack of skill and knowledge which is the reason I came here to ask.

What I'm curious about is this.

let's suppose an array like below

```
array(4){

  [0]=>
  array(3){
    ["a"] => 
    string(3) "abc"
    ["b"] => 
    string(3) "123"
    ["c"] => 
    string(3) "a15"

  }

  [1]=>
  array(3){
    ["a"] => 
    string(3) "def"
    ["b"] => 
    string(3) "456"
    ["c"] => 
    string(3) "5g2"
  }

  [2]=>
  array(3){
    ["a"] => 
    string(3) "ghi"
    ["b"] => 
    string(3) "123"
    ["c"] => 
    string(3) "79h"
  }


  [3]=>
  array(3){
    ["a"] => 
    string(3) "jkl"
    ["b"] => 
    string(3) "091"
    ["c"] => 
    string(3) "8b9"
  }




}
```

as you can see This is an array that has four arrays in it.
and here are things I want to get from this array.

1. a new array that has other arrays that the value of  key "b" is "123"

so my expectation would be like below:

```
array(2){

[0]=>
array(3){
  ["a"] => 
  string(3) "abc"
  ["b"] => 
  string(3) "123"
  ["c"] => 
  string(3) "a15"

}


[1]=>
array(3){
  ["a"] => 
  string(3) "ghi"
  ["b"] => 
  string(3) "123"
  ["c"] => 
  string(3) "79h"
}

}
```

and the second thing I want to get is an also array that has remains of arrays

it would be like below:

```
array(2){

[0]=>
array(3){
  ["a"] => 
  string(3) "def"
  ["b"] => 
  string(3) "456"
  ["c"] => 
  string(3) "5g2"
}

[1]=>
array(3){
  ["a"] => 
  string(3) "jkl"
  ["b"] => 
  string(3) "091"
  ["c"] => 
  string(3) "8b9"
}

}
```

to get those arrays, I tried to use array_splice and array_slice but couldn't since
their start point($offset) must be a number, not a conditional statement.
(https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)
(https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

do you guys have any idea how to build this function? Share it with me please, if you have one

Thx for reading, your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a condition inside foreach loop.

So assuming that your array with all items is `$original`:

```
$a = [];
$b = [];

foreach($original as $single){
 if($single['b'] == '123') {
  $a[] = $single;
 }else{
  $b[] = $single;
 }
}
```

This code will give you two new arrays in the end, `$a` and `$b`, one containing items that fulfil the condition and the other without it.

Comment: I appreciate it a lot!!! you saved me :)